# apache deny directive not working

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

Solution:
I have to put the allow/deny directives inside the first Directory directive(which also happens to be for the root).  I'm guessing it's because it has a AllowOverride None that does't allow any children to specify allow/deny?

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
        Deny from xxx.xx.xxx.xx
</Directory>
```

Original:

This configuration still allows access to all IPs after apache restart

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  www.xxx.com

    DocumentRoot  /var/www/vhosts/xxx

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/xxx>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all                     
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So you did have two <Directory> directive's like I surmised? Putting that directive on the root is an unusual step.

Comment: As Patrick R commented on question, putting a Directory directive with same path as documentroot cause troubles. I have similar problem in my apache config. I resolved just disabling the problematic Directory and writing options directly in virtualhost directive.

Answer (score 2):

That should work. I just verified your code on my server to make sure I wasn't crazy. Are you sure you don't have a definition before this one that is taking precedence?

Create a test file in the folder on your server.  Something like test.txt.  You may find that you don't see it when you load that url in your browser.  If that's the case then your definition above is getting skipped.

Comment: There's an `AllowOverride none` so, a .htaccess should not be able to do anything.

Comment: Right again Mat.  I'll remove that from what I said.

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that your <Directory> conditions will still be skipped altogether even if you used Mat's good answer.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, that is, only allow 127.0.0.1, you should do the following :

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Which says first, `allow` things, then `deny` things, and `deny` things that did not match.

You should also not put your `<Directory>` block inside your `<VirtualHost>` one, but before it.

Comment: Mat's definition should work.  I'm still curious as to why yours doesn't.

Comment: @Mat - I think I'm misunderstanding you.  Are you suggesting that one put the <Directory> block outside of the <VirtualHost> block?  I must be misunderstanding you.  How will the <Directory> be applied to the appropriate virtualhost?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Plesk system? Sometimes you have to watch how the various http includes are being compiled. You may have something in a later include file that is over writing your first statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. this code works.

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

NameVirtualHost 192.168.44.141

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1 192.168.44.141>

#ServerName localhost.com
    ServerName www.localhost.com
DocumentRoot  "E:/abcd"
<Directory "E:/abcd/files">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.44.128
    Deny from all

  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it works either use "Allow from" or "Deny from" in VirtualHost block. If i try to use both lines in VirtualHost block, it will not properly work.